# How can i add pull to fresh option in swipe tabs in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I want to add pull to fresh option in swipe tabs but it's not working I have taken container also and try to add it but its seems to same.

Here is my code

```
displayContainer   = new Container();
getDisplay(displayContainer);
    for(i=0;i<totalRadioButton;i++){
        tabs.hideTabs();
        displayContainer   = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        getDisplay(displayContainer);
        tabs.addTab("",displayContainer);
        //tabs.add(flowContainer);
        tabs.setName("t"+i);
        tabs.setTabUIID(tabs.getName());
        radioButton =new RadioButton();
        radioButton.setName("rbt"+i);
        radioTypeContainer.add(radioButton);
        finalRadioList.add(radioButton.getName());
        tabsListName.add(tabs.getTabUIID());
        radioList.add(radioButton);
        tabIndex0="rbt0";
        if(radioList.get(i).getName().equals(tabIndex0)){
            radioList.get(i).setSelected(true); 
        }
        buttonGroup.addAll(radioButton);


    }

tabs.getContentPane().addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              getMyList();

            }
        });
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to put the pull to refresh on the displayContainer

Comment: I added likes this but till not working.

displayContainer.addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  displayContainer.removeAll();
                  getDisplay(displayContainer);  
                  tabs.addTab("",displayContainer);
                  displayContainer.revalidate();
                }
            });

Comment: If you make changes to your code and say it's still not working, please update your question with the new code.

Comment: It's working actually i forget to add this line displayContainer1.setScrollableY(true);

Answer (score 0):

As Chen mentioned you need to add it to `displayContainer` but notice that it needs to be Y scrollable to work. I would suggest placing the whole `Tabs` container into the center of a border layout so it's parent is scrollable.